# finding the remote IP address used by a mounted SMB share

Tags: terminal, network, smb, nas

Using Finder, I have mounted an SMB share which resides on my NAS . When I use the mount command, the NAS is listed with the name it advertises (`nas-smb`).

```
mbp:~ me$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
//me@nas-smb._smb._tcp.local/myshare on /Volumes/myshare (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by me)
```

Edit:
<strike>Is there a way to translate this to the IP address of the NAS or otherwise learn this information?</strike>
Is there any way to find out the IP address of the NAS which is used to mount this share?

The tricky part is that my NAS can be reached on two different IP addresses (direct wired 1Gbps and wireless through my router).

On different sessions from the transfer speeds alone I have concluded that either of the IP addresses were in use. So I can't definitely tell to which of the two addresses I am connected for the SMB sharing.

The `host` command didn't works only with the wireless interface. I have also tried `lsof -i -n` but it shows no SMB related connections.

I hoped that `smbutil lookup nas-smb` could tell me what I want, but it doesn't. When the speeds show that the wired interface is in use, it still returns the address of the wireless interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it is advertising its presence on the network with Bonjour, you should be able to simply ping it:

```
ping -c 1 nas-smb.local
```

Comment: This does work after all! Just make sure you don't omit the `.local` part! (Like I did when I first tried it.)

Answer (score 12):

I had problem of finding IP of maching which is not even behind NAT. Finder shows the name Bonjour Exporer and ping does not resolve it. Finally `smbutil lookup <name>` worked for me.

Comment: The OP explicitly stated that `smbutil lookup` didn't work for him. Are you using it differently and if yes, how?

Comment: Even if the OP can't use this answer - perhaps it will confirm for others to re-try the `smbutil` or perhaps all the factors in making the problem are not common for all people. (the problem is something unrelated perhaps)